# Puppeteer: how to download entire web page for offline use

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-scraping, puppeteer

How would I scrape an entire website, with all of its CSS/JavaScript/media intact (and not just its HTML), with Google's Puppeteer? After successfully trying it out on other scraping jobs, I would imagine it should be able to.

However, looking through the many excellent examples online, there is no obvious method for doing so. The closest I have been able to find is calling

```
html_contents = await page.content()
```

and saving the results, but that saves a copy without any non-HTML elements.

Is there way to save webpages for offline use with Puppeteer?

Comment: Puppeteer won't implement this https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/2433

Comment: Well.. that is surprising to me, as I can't think of a good reason why they wouldn't implement that. At any rate, I hope someone has made a third-party extension in that case.

Comment: @hardkoded There is an experimental way, see answer below.

Comment: Hi Coolio. Please do not (re)add conversational material to questions. Broadly, the readership here prefer a technical approach to writing, as succinctness is thought to add clarity. Gratitude is assumed by readers, and is best expressed in upvoting/acceptance.

Comment: I do not agree with that assertion, as writing clearly demands a bit of a relaxed touch, but you are the mod, so fair enough.

Answer (score 38):

It is currently possible via experimental CDP call [`'Page.captureSnapshot'`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page#method-captureSnapshot) using [MHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) format:

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML');

    const cdp = await page.target().createCDPSession();
    const { data } = await cdp.send('Page.captureSnapshot', { format: 'mhtml' });
    fs.writeFileSync('page.mhtml', data);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: I will wait a bit to see if someone has managed to make a fork of Puppeteer that saves sites perfectly for offline use, but until then thanks for your clear example.
Is there any news on how much development `captureSnapshot` is getting? As you yourself implied, it is missing a lot of features, though is slightly better than a raw html copy.

Comment: I am not aware of the details, sorry. If this format suffices,  this depends on the needs of using the result.

Comment: I have seen lot using cdp session, can you pls tell for what is used and where it is useful ?

Comment: @RajSaraogi CDP is the protocol on which puppeteer's work is based, so it provides more posibilities than puppeteer's "suggar" API. See more here: https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/

Comment: @vsemozhebuty after downloading the offline page, how can I load it using puppeteer? I tried `goto('site.mhtml')` but I receive `Error: net::ERR_ABORTED`

Comment: @itaied If I understand correctly, you need the full absolute path to the file like `file:///path/to/site.mhtml`.