# Puppeteer not saving scripts of scraped site

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I scraped a website using Puppeteer as follows:

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(url);
  const html = await page.content();
  fs.writeFileSync("./pages/index.html", html);
  await browser.close();
```

The page is scraped but without some of the functionality. For example, hovering on menu button does not show menu.

What I tried:

- I inspected the menu button on the original site. When I hover on the button, a class is be added to the menu element and make the menu visible.
- I checked the `console` on my scraped version and found several errors that say "failed to load resources" and some of those errors were pointing to Webpack `.js` files.

How can I scrape the page with its scripts and possibly any other resources that it needs?

Comment: It's hard to help without the site. That said, if you're just saving the HTML and trying to load it locally, many resources are probably blocked due to CORS. The site expects to be run on the server you're scraping it from, not your localhost or any other server. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @ggorlen I want to download the site, modify some elements and upload it to another server. This is a task I was given in a job interview.

Comment: Thanks. It seems you'll need to download and host any other resources such as scripts that you want to work on your server (I think you understand this based on your post, now that I'm reading more closely). One way to do that is to capture all network requests and download each of those resources. [Puppeteer: how to download entire web page for offline use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54814323/puppeteer-how-to-download-entire-web-page-for-offline-use) might be another approach.